# FragmentPagerAdapter keeps not visible fragment menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-viewpager

I'm using menu provider to create option menu specific by fragment, fragments are managed by `viewpager + FragmentPagerAdapter`

```
 (requireActivity() as MenuHost).addMenuProvider(
    object : MenuProvider {
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(menuRes, menu)
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            return callback(menuItem.itemId)
        }

    }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
)
```

additionally I have one menu provider from activity and want to keep it for every fragment. Everything works fine but found some adge case:

Activity keeps another fragment's menu option from viewpager if I will changed current item manually, for view pager ( for navigation reason)

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(index, true) or
pageChangeListener.onPageSelected(index)
```